# Why does my MenuItem icon not show at the top level in Electron 1.8.1?

Tags: electron, menuitem

I have an Electron app with a menu. The first menu item is a drop-down so it has a submenu. The other two menu items just do their stuff on clicking.
My problem is that I just cannot get an icon to be shown for the menu items that do their stuff straight away. (The same icon displays fine on submenu items.)
As in:

```
const {
  BrowserWindow,
  Menu, app
} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
viewerWindow = null;

// define the menus
var menuoptions = [
    {
        label: "Select All", // {role: 'selectAll' } doesn't show the keyboard shortcuts
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+A',
        click: () => viewerWindow.webContents.selectAll()
    },
    {
        label: "Copy", // {role: 'copy'} doesn't show the keyboard shortcuts
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+C',
        click: () => viewerWindow.webContents.copy()
    },

    {type:'separator'}, 
    {
        id: 'b',
        label:'Back',
        icon: 'C:/Users/bvanlogg/Documents/ElectronFiddle/point_left.png',
        accelerator: 'Alt+Left',
        click() {
            nav.goBack()
        }
    },
    {
        id: 'f',
        label:'Forward',
        icon: 'C:/Users/bvanlogg/Documents/ElectronFiddle/point_right.png',
        accelerator: 'Alt+Right',
        click() {
            nav.goForward()
        }
    },
    {type:'separator'}, 
    {role: 'toggledevtools'},
    {role: 'quit'}
]

const contextmenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuoptions)
const toolsmenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([{
    label: 'Tools',
    submenu: menuoptions
},
{type:'separator'}, 
{type:'separator'}, 
{type:'separator'}, 
{type:'separator'}, 
{
    id: 'bb',
    icon: 'C:/Users/bvanlogg/Documents/ElectronFiddle/point_left.png',
    label:'Back',
    click() {
        nav.goBack()
    }
},
{
    id: 'ff',
    label:'Forward',
    icon: 'C:/Users/bvanlogg/Documents/ElectronFiddle/point_right.png',
    click() {
        nav.goForward()
    }
}
])
Menu.setApplicationMenu(toolsmenu);

// start the renderer
app.on('ready', () => {
    viewerWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        x: 336,
        y: 280, 
        height: 601,
        width: 1248, 
        show: false
    })
    viewerWindow.setMenu(toolsmenu);
    viewerWindow.webContents.on('context-menu', e => {
        contextmenu.popup()
    })
    docurl = path.resolve(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
    viewerWindow.loadURL(docurl);

    viewerWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
        viewerWindow.show();
    })



})
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function ()
{
    app.quit();
})
```

The icon is simply not shown. If I take out the label, nothing is shown.
But the icon **is** shown when I put exactly the same code inside a submenu. I've [created a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxXde.png) showing the specified icons next to the options in the submenu but not to those in the main menu:

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproduction (e.g. using https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle) and specify which OS you're encountering the problem on? It'd make it easier to debug the issue.

Also, I don't think Electron _has_ an v1.1.8 release. It seems like the v1.1.X release branch stopped at 1.1.3 (https://github.com/electron/releases)

Comment: I am sorry, yes, indeed there was a typo and I am using Electron 1.8.1.

Comment: As to using an Electron Fiddle, I am running into problems there because the Fiddle looks for relatively-referenced files in my tmp directory so requires an absolute path for my icon file; and this kind of defeats the purpose of posting a minimal reproduction. I shall go back to my original question and try to edit it so as to make things clearer. Thank you for your help!